# Angular cant find some modules

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a project in Angular 11. I tried to update the Angular Material library from version 10 to version 12. Afterward, all my Node-Modules collapsed.

I tried to remove the folder and reinstall the packages. I am getting few errors. Image attached for reference. Please advise.

[image]

Comment: What i can tell from the image is that you dont have any modules installed!

Comment: After updating the packages, did you execute "npm install". Because I am not seeing the "node_modules" folder

Comment: In which folder did you run the `npm install`? To make it work, you have to do this in the root folder (where the `package.json` is).

Answer (score 1):

run npm install in your cmd where your project is, it will update all the node modules, it worked for me

npm i